# Google Forms API - navigation pages (Go to Section) don't work as configured

Tags: navigation, form-submit, google-forms-api

I'm using the Google Forms API to create a form where one of the alternatives is "submit this form" while the others will collect the necessary information, as in the example below:
[image]

[image]
The created form seems ok. However, when opening the form, instead of having the last option pointing to Section 2, it shows "Submit Form".

Form link: https://forms.gle/J5aQwFLHFuv635Vd8

Bellow you will find the code:

```html
function SampleFormCreation() {

  var sampleForm =  FormApp.create('Sample form lu.c.n'); 
  sampleFormUrl = sampleForm.getEditUrl();

  var item = sampleForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setTitle('Choose one')
      .setChoiceValues(['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
      .setRequired(true);
  item = sampleForm.addDateItem();
 

  // Add Page break and dropdown menu
  mainPage = sampleForm.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Main Page');
  sampleSelectionItem = sampleForm.addListItem().setTitle('sample selection')
                                                .setRequired(true);
  
  var pages = [];
  var itemChoices = [];  
 
  // Add one page for each blood measure that can be a number greater than zero or a multiple choice
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pages[i] = sampleForm.addPageBreakItem().setTitle( 'Option' + (i+1));
    item = sampleForm.addTextItem();
    item.setTitle('option' + (i+1)).setRequired(false);
    pages[i].setGoToPage(mainPage); 
  }

  // Add the dropdown choices for blood Test selection.  First option should be "Submit Form"
  itemChoices.push(sampleSelectionItem.createChoice('Submit Form', FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT));
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    itemChoices.push(sampleSelectionItem.createChoice('option' + (i+1), pages[i]));
  }
  
  sampleSelectionItem.setChoices(itemChoices);
}
```

It seems the issue is in the Google Form UI. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code that generated this form sample so that the community will have better idea of what happened in the process of generation?

Comment: Sure! Let me add it

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit of your question for better oversight in your project. For starters, this is expected behavior as the last section typically marks the end of the form, where respondents submit their answers. There's no need for branching logic at this point, as there are no further sections to navigate to. As said it only breaks progression and the last pages don't have one. I suggest just skipping getting information on the last page and keeping it to the submit form or you can issue a feature request at [https://issuetracker.google.com/](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will have a large dropdown menu and users are supposed to go forth and  back to section 2 for few times. If they select the last option they are not supposed to submit their form.  I tried to add a null section/question after that, but it doesn't change anything at all.   I would expect the form to work as it was configured but this is not the case. I will have to discard the form I've envisioned and work in a different alternative.